# Applying purrr::walk2() to a data.frame of data.frames at the end of a pipe

Tags: r, purrr

I have an R data frame, with one column of data frames, each of which I want to print to a file:

```
df0 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))
df1 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))
df2 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))

animalFrames <- tibble(animals = c('sheep', 'cow', 'horse'),
                       frames = list(df0, df1, df2))
```

I could do this with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:dim(animalFrames)[1]){
    write.csv(animalFrames[i,2][[1]], file = paste0('test_', animalFrames[i,1], '.csv'))
}
```

Or with `purrr`'s `walk2` function:

```
walk2(animalFrames$animals, animalFrames$frames,  ~write.csv(.y, file
= paste0('test_', .x, '.csv')))
```

Is there some way I can put this walk function at the end of a `magrittr` pipe?

I was thinking something like:

```
animalFrames %>% do({walk2(.$animals, .$frames, ~write.csv(.y, file = paste0('test_', .x, '.csv')))})
```

But this gives me an error:

> ```
> Error: Result must be a data frame, not character
> Traceback:
>
> 1. animalFrames %>% do({
>  .     walk2(.$animals, .$frames, ~write.csv(.y, file = paste0("test_", 
>  .         .x, ".csv")))
>  . })
> 2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
> 8. function_list[[k]](value)
> 9. do(., {
>  .     walk2(.$animals, .$frames, ~write.csv(.y, file = paste0("test_", 
>  .         .x, ".csv")))
>  . })
> 10. do.data.frame(., {
>   .     walk2(.$animals, .$frames, ~write.csv(.y, file = paste0("test_", 
>   .         .x, ".csv")))
>   . })
> 11. bad("Result must be a data frame, not {fmt_classes(out)}")
> 12. glubort(NULL, ..., .envir = parent.frame())
> 13. .abort(text)
> ```

Presumably because `write.csv()` is returning data frames and `do()` doesn't handle those or something.

I don't really have a coding requirement that I have to put walk at the end of a pipe (Indeed, I can always work around pipes), but it seems like I am missing something basic and this is bugging me.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need `do` at all. Both of the following work for me. The first is simply the same as yours minus `do` I think, the second makes use of `magrittr`'s convenient `%$%` operator to expose the column names to `walk2` and avoid the `.$`. Note that if this is at the end of a pipe it doesn't matter much whether you use `walk2` or `map2` since you don't care what's returned after this step.

NB I also swapped out `paste0` and `write.csv` for `tidyverse` equivalents out of habit but they're easily put back in.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df0 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))
df1 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))
df2 <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3))

animalFrames <- tibble(animals = c('sheep', 'cow', 'horse'),
                       frames = list(df0, df1, df2))

animalFrames %>%
  walk2(
    .x = .$animals,
    .y = .$frames,
    .f = ~ write_csv(.y, str_c("test_", .x, ".csv"))
  )

library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract
animalFrames %$%
  walk2(
    .x = animals,
    .y = frames,
    .f = ~ write_csv(.y, str_c("test_", .x, ".csv"))
  )
```

Created on 2018-03-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

### Use purrr::pwalk()

Very similar to the fantastic answer given by Calum You, but shorter and (in my opinion) slightly more elegant.

`pwalk()` walks across many list elements in parallel. It's mostly used to do `walk()` on more than two vectors. But because a tibble is a named list of columns, we can pass the whole tibble to `pwalk()` and each column becomes an argument which is passed to `.f` for parallel evaluation.

The shortest solution uses `~` notation based on column locations, but you can also write a function which accepts arguments with the same names as your columns:

```r
## using column locations (`~` notation) ---------------------
animalFrames |> 
  pwalk(
    .f = ~ write.csv(.y, file = paste0("test_", .x, ".csv"))
  )

## using column names & custom function ----------------------
## (longer, more robust, perhaps more readable) --------------

save_file <- function(animals, frames){
  write.csv(frames, file = paste0("test_", animals, ".csv"))
}

animalFrames |> pwalk(save_file)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>